# Running NuSMV on Mac

Tags: macos, cmake, model-checking, nusmv

I downloaded NuSMV source code for mac and started installing using the README. However, there is a step which asks me to build using 'cmake..' when I run that I get the issue The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *NuSMV* **binaries** certainly do not need to be compiled, so I conclude that you downloaded the **sources** package of *NuSMV*.

The file `CmakeLists.txt` **is** contained in `..../NuSMV-<version>/NuSMV`.

Check again that you created the `build` directory within such path *[as the `README.txt` file asks you to do]*, or simply set the argument of the `cmake <path>` command to correctly point to the path `..../NuSMV-<version>/NuSMV`.

Comment: yes source code not binaries. 

It's all working now, however I can't make NuSMV actually run

Comment: you should update your question with the new error, or make a new question

Comment: I have done that here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662953/running-nusmv-on-osx