# Running NuSMV on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, model-checking, nusmv

I have installed NuSMV using the readme provided, however when I try to use the NuSMV command, I get the following message:
-bash: NuSMV: command not found

There isn't much information on the internet about this, so I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Did you try to append the `bin` directory including the *NuSMV* executable that you just built to the `PATH` variable, and export it?

Comment: this was the last step I did % export NUSMV_LIBRARY_PATH=[...]/<TOPDIR>/NuSMV/share/nusmv

I do have a bin directory with NuSMV executable

Comment: I mean to the `PATH` variable

Comment: yes i've included this, export PATH="$HOME/nusmv/NuSMV-2.6.0/NuSMV/build/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to my home directory, and creating a new bash profile and appending the bin directory with the NuSMV executable made it work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

How to make it work on MacOSX

---

got to this link : http://nusmv.fbk.eu/

click
NuSMV 2.6.0 is OUT!

Select : NuSMV binaries
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJzGf.png)

Fill out the details and register : you will be able to download a zip file, extract it and copy it anywhere you want. Now we need to set the path.

Open terminal and do something like this:
Add the directory /opt/nusmv-X.Y.Z/bin to your command
search PATH environment variable. E.g. for bash shell:

> % export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/nusmv-X.Y.Z/bin

set the NUSMV_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable. E.g. for bash shell:

> % export NUSMV_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/nusmv-X.Y.Z/share/nusmv

Now you are ready to run and enjoy NuSMV.

> % NuSMV -int   # to run the interactive mode