# NuSMV command not found Mac

Tags: nusmv

I downloaded the NuSMV binary (MacOSX Darwin (x86) 64-bit).

After I unpacked it, I traveled to the bin folder in terminal.

I tried the command NuSMV -int, but I get an error : 
-bash: NuSMV: command not found

I tried to temporarily alter the path :
PATH=$PATH:/Users/buzz/Desktop/Hunter/NuSMV/bin
echo $PATH

When I echo, I see the path is there. 
I try again, same error.

If I open the file in the bin manually, labeled NuSMV, it aborts :

Input file is (null). You must set the input file before.

Aborting batch mode

NuSMV terminated by a signal

How do I get the NuSMV command to work in terminal?

Thank you

Comment: Navigate to the directory in which the binary of `NuSMV` is present and type `export PATH=`pwd`:$PATH`, then check again.

Comment: Also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662953/running-nusmv-on-osx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Not sure why, but I had to type ./NuSMV, or something like that, and it worked

"./" made it work.

Comment: that doesn't really solve the problem in the question, though I guess is a possible workaround.