# How to install and run NuSMV on Mac?

Tags: macos, installation, nusmv

I have to install NuSMV on my mac and i don't know exactly how to install it. There are two files available on NuSMV website, one is SourceCode and other is binary. Which one should i install? And after choosing what should i do, Like should i follow readme.txt or what? Any help will be appreciated as there isn't much help on internet regarding NuSMV installation for mac.
P.S :- I have already tried installing Source code part and installed it according to readme.txt but i don't know what i am missing as i also don't know what is the procedure to run a smv file.

Comment: Possibly useful [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657806/running-nusmv-on-mac)

Comment: Another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662953/running-nusmv-on-osx?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Although I see some value in answering the question in the title with a sufficient level of detail, the answer would be a trivial copy-and-paste of the `INSTALLING NUSMV` section contained in the `README.txt` file. What is the exact problem you are stuck with? How can other people reproduce your issue?